# Oracle Text query rewrite template not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

Why are the two last rewrite rules in the example from Oracle documentation not working?

Source http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#i1007557

> Query applications sometimes parse end user queries, interpreting a
>   query string in one or more ways using different operator
>   combinations. For example, if a user enters a query of kukui nut, your
>   application might enter the queries {kukui nut} and {kukui or nut} to
>   increase recall.
>
> The query rewrite feature enables you to submit a single query that
>   expands the original query into the rewritten versions. The results
>   are returned with no duplication.
>
> You specify your rewrite sequences with the query template feature.
>   The rewritten versions of the query are executed efficiently with a
>   single call to CONTAINS or CATSEARCH.
>
> The following template defines a query rewrite sequence. The query of
>   {kukui nut} is rewritten as follows:
>
> {kukui} {nut}
>
> {kukui} ; {nut}
>
> {kukui} AND {nut}
>
> {kukui} ACCUM {nut}
>
> The query rewrite template for these transformations is as follows:
>
> ```
> select id from docs where CONTAINS (text,
>  '<query>
>    <textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT"> kukui nut
>      <progression>
>        <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " "))</rewrite></seq>
>        <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " ; "))</rewrite></seq>
>        <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", "AND"))</rewrite></seq>
>        <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", "ACCUM"))</rewrite></seq>
>      </progression>
>    </textquery>
>   <score datatype="INTEGER" algorithm="COUNT"/>
> </query>')>0;
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in the example provided by Oracle. It is essential that the query operators are separated with spaces:

```
<seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " AND "))</rewrite></seq>
<seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " ACCUM "))</rewrite></seq>
```

so " AND " and " ACCUM " instead of "AND" and "ACCUM" as in the documentation.